# Python for / if constructs

Tags: python

why do neither of these work as a loop construct

```
for x in text.lower() if x.isalpha():
for x in text.lower() if x.isalpha()
```

when this works just fine in the optimal solution of a kata on codewars

```
return ' '.join(str(ord(c) - 96) for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()
```

(I wrote my loops in a more "non python" traditional way, but I knew when I submitted that I would see a more "pythony" solution which did the same thing but in much less code. My problem here is I'm not sure why

```
for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()
```

is OK as part of a single line return statement but neither

```
for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()
for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha():
```

does not work as a line on its own as a loop construct (I added the colon but the interpreter complained with or without a colon so then I realized the problem is something else

Comment: Python doesn’t allow those forms of ‘for’ loops.

Comment: That's a comprehension generator.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "why"? The obvious answer is "because it is not valid Python". Are you asking why the maintainers did not include this? Are you asking in general if there are reasons not to do this?

Comment: I don't know what answer you expect to get except: *This is the language's syntax rules...*

Comment: the answer I was looking for as a beginner was
"even though the expression
for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()

is the exact same text, they are NOT identical in terms of constructing a for loop or a generator to a return function.

As a beginner I was focussing on the syntax of the expression itself which is already a bit of a new style to me, and not realizing that having the expression as a for loop by itself and within a return statement are NOT the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` keyword is used for two related but not equal things:

- A [`for` *statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) is a classical loop working on a *block* of statements for each iteration step.

  ```py
  for <target> in <iterable>:
        <block>
  ```

  Notably, the `for` statement can run arbitrary blocks, including but not limited to `if`statements.
- A [`for` display *expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) is part of a fixed expression (`list`, `set`, `dict` comprehension or generator expression) to *map* and *filter* iterables.

  ```py
  [<map> for <target> in <iterable> if <filter>]
  ```

  Notably, the `for`–`in`–`if` are a fixed expression syntax with well-defined meaning *only when used together*.

The `for` statement does not have to be special-cased with an `if`, since it can include a regular `if` statement. The `for` display must be special-cased with an `if`, since the latter is defined in terms of the former.

Comment: Thank you. I am not asking "why" as in why didn't they make this work, but the other replies "this is the syntax of python" was exactly my question.

WHAT is the difference between the two, I am new to python and now realize that the for-in-if construct is a separately defined syntax, thanks!

It is not at all obvious to a beginner that they are different when the expression looks identical "for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()" in both cases.

thank you very much for the helpful reply!

Answer (score 0):

Python does not allow this kind of for loops, you can try a list comprehension

```
[c for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()]
```

If you need `else`:

```
[c if c.isalpha() else a for c in text.lower()]
```

Or even you can use `set`,`dict` etc. comprehensions or generators

Comment: thanks, maybe it was unclear that I am a beginner. I'm not looking for solutions per se, I had not understood that the expression
for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()

is two different things as a for loop and as this comprehension(/generator in the return output.

Now I know I will read up a bit more on this.

Answer (score 0):

You must split that construct into two lines:

```
for c in text:
    if c.isalpha():
    pass
```

(You need not lowercase the text.)

Comment: thanks, again, I wasn't looking to fix anything, now that I know the answer, my question was actually

what is the difference between "for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()" when used as a for loop or a generator/comprehension. Its just not allowed in the former but is in the latter, but that these are TWO SEPARATE types of thing is not at all obvious to a beginner when the actual expression from the word "for" to the isalpha() is identical :)